# How can I implement hideOnScroll for Android in react-native-navigation V2?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I have added wix react native navigation V2 in my react project. I want to hide top navbar on scroll in Android. I see option 'hideOnScroll' in documentaion, but its only for ios. How can I implement same for Android?

Answer (score 0):

I made it with this configuration:

```
component: {
  name: SOME_NAME,
  options: {
    topBar: {
      visible: true,
      hideOnScroll: true,
      buttonColor: 'white',
      drawBehind: true,
    },
  },
},
```

It's working for me with Android and iOS